# emacs lisp error : Need a pre-parsed url

Tags: debugging, url, defstruct

I'm trying to use `tern` with the latest version of `emacs` (27 : master branch) and I'm getting the following error :

> Request failed: `((wrong-type-argument Need a pre-parsed URL.
>   [cl-struct-url http nil nil 127.0.0.1 39585 / nil nil nil nil t] url))`

Basically : `tern` is unable to perform any kind of request because of this error.
It seems to come from `tern-req` function in [tern.el](https://github.com/ternjs/tern/blob/master/emacs/tern.el), this line :

```
(url (url-parse-make-urlobj "http" nil nil tern-server port "/" nil nil nil))
```

But I don't know how to fix it, 'cause I'm not really familiar with lisp development.

I've opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/ternjs/tern/issues/965), but since "Tern is not being actively maintained right now.", I'm asking here

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you need emacs master?

Comment: For xwidgets and packages that are only supported since emacs26

Comment: Please do not post the same question to emacs.SE and StackOverflow. Choose one or the other. Please delete one of the questions. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tern` package was compiled with the older Emacs, but the newer Emacs has changed the representation of structs: the `[cl-struct-url http nil nil 127.0.0.1 39585 / nil nil nil nil t]` in your error message is an "old-style" struct, returned by the old `url-parse-make-urlobj`.  This happens because this function was inlined when tern was compiled.

You can try to enable `(cl-old-struct-compat-mode 1)` which was designed to try and accommodate those circumstances.  If that fails to solve your problem then you'll need to recompile your `tern` package.